# deleting unaccessed files using python

Tags: python, file, time

My `django app` parses some files uploaded by the user.It is possible that the file uploaded by the user may remain in the server for a long time ,without it being parsed by the app.This can increase in size if a lot of users upload a lot of files.

I need to delete those files not recently parsed by the app -say `not accessed for last 24 hours`.I tried like this

```
import os
import time

dirname = MEDIA_ROOT+my_folder
filenames = os.listdir(dirname)
filenames = [os.path.join(dirname,filename) for filename in filenames]
for filename in filenames:
    last_access = os.stat(filename).st_atime #secs since epoch
    rtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(last_access))
    print filename+'----'+rtime
```

This shows the last accessed times for each file..But I am not sure how I can test if the file access time was within the last 24 hours..Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `time.time()`. It will allow you to access the current timestamp, in utc time. You can then subtract the current stamp from the file timestamp and see if it's greater than 24*60*60.

http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time

Also, keep in mind that a lot of the time, a Linux filesystem is mounted with noatime, meaning the st_atime variable might not be populated. You should probably use st_mtime, just to be safe, unless you're 100% sure the filesystem will always be mounted with atimes recorded.

Here's what should be a working example, I haven't debugged though.

```
import os
import time

dirname = MEDIA_ROOT+my_folder
filenames = os.listdir(dirname)
filenames = [os.path.join(dirname,filename) for filename in filenames]
for filename in filenames:
    last_access = os.stat(filename).st_mtime #secs since epoch
    timediff = time.gmtime() - last_access
    print filename+'----'+timediff
    if timediff > 24*60*60:
        print 'older than a day'
        # do your thing
```

Comment: but `time.gmtime()` will give a time_struct which is incompatible with `last_access` ..maybe will have to use `time.mktime(...)` to convert it

Comment: ahh, you're right damon. it would have to be `mktime(gmtime())`, or just using the `time` function. Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with actual dates? Just check whether `os.stat(filename).st_atime < time.time() - 24*60*60`.